# Ambari agent memory leak can't fix

Tags: ambari

Ambari-2.1.2,HDP-2.3.2.0-2950

Noticed to many resident memory for the agents on a cluster that is running for few day.

I found a solution.

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/21253/ambari-agent-memory-leak-or-taking-too-much-memory.html https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-17539

I have modified the code for main.py, but the agent still has memory leak. The following is the code I added

```
[main.py]https://community.hortonworks.com/storage/attachments/34791-mainpy.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, in older Ambari versions, there was a memory leak because a new log formatter was created every time the logging has been invoked.
Anyway, the best solution would be to upgrade to newer Ambari version. Stack 2.3 is widely supported